# Blender crashes when I click domain in the options for smoke

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I've been using Blender for awhile on and off. I recently decided to dive into making fire so I looked up tutorials on how to simulate fire but immediately ran into problems. I couldn't get it to work following the tutorials so I downloaded the newest version 2.72b. My old version was 2.66. I think I may have a few issues so I'm not sure what to do.

The immediate problem I'm faced with is when I start with the starter program with just the cube and I'm in "object mode"and have done nothing else at all and I go straight to the physics tab, select "smoke" then when I click on "domain" the program crashes. By crashes, I mean it simply closes the program without saving anything. The only way it doesn't crash is if I go to "edit mode" first then click "domain". But I read somewhere you don't want to do that because it will double render the smoke or something like that. At any rate, even if I do it in "edit mode" then click F12 to render, as soon as I click Esc, it crashes anyway. It also crashes if I go back to "object mode". I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's something else like hardware issue, or just a bug in the program.

I think I may have more than one thing going wrong here though.

Problems I think I may have but need help answering:

1.) When I downloaded the new version 2.72b I didn't do anything with the old version. I left it right where the installer had originally installed it by default. I let the default also install version 2.72b as well. I'm not sure if I've corrupted parts of the program by doing this. I'm hoping the install program simply overwrote dll files to avoid duplicates and what not.

2.) I fear the real problem is my computers ability. The computer is rather old. It's an old Gateway GT5628. I worried the problem is it doesn't have a separate graphics card for GPU use/settings. I can only use CPU. It has an Intel (R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.4GHz with 4GB DDR3 RAM. The operation system is Windows Vista 32-bit.

Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated. I've exhausted myself trying to find answers and fear I'm doing more harm than good by trying to figure it out myself such as Installing the newest version of Blender without knowing exactly how to install it properly. Anyways...

Looking forward to some answers.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Does Blender also crash when you start with the default scene: select the cube and [Space] and enter [quick smoke]? Run simulation [Alt]-[A] If this works you could change settings and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Yes, It crashes when I select "object", "quick effects", "quick smoke".

Comment: Sorry for not posting in the proper area. I lack knowledge of where to post questions and was really unsure of where to post my problem because I really don't know what the problem is. Weather it's just a user error, hardware issue or an actual bug in the program.

Comment: It sounds like a bug report, mostly crashes like the one you described are caused by an outdated graphic driver. It is not a user error because it works for everybody. You could try to get an update. If it basically works this would be the right place to ask for details.

Comment: Ah... Ok. So in the future, if I have a crash issue don't post where I posted. Post it to "Blender's tracker"? Not sure where that is but I'll figure it out. Hopefully... lol As for the "update" to my graphics driver... I'll see if that's the issue. Not really sure how to do that either but I'll hopefully figure that out too. Thank you for your assistance. I really appreciate it.

Comment: sorry if this sounded bureaucratic, can you access some other computer just to test this? You have a say 99% change that it will work flawless. Neither the developers would fix a incompatibility nor one of us could help.

Comment: Yeah, I do have another much beefier computer that the program would very likely work flawlessly on. It has an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.4GHz, Windows 8 64-bit, graphics card GeForce GTX 680 and 16GB DDR5 RAM. Problem is, my darn fiance uses that computer all the time, for her email and facebook that just sooooooo needs all that computing power. lol I'll have to talk her into using this one instead so I can use the other one. I use to use it but it ended up somehow getting a virus so I had to install a new OEM Windows 8 on it which made me lose everything on that computer. Anyways...

Comment: Do you think uninstalling Blender and then reinstalling it might fix my problem or is that not recommended?

Comment: @chirs I don't think think re-installing blender would change anything. According to http://sciencespaces.com/notebooks/gateway/gateway-gt5628/21694/ you have Nvidia 8600m, try this driver: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/57621/en-us

Comment: Thank you for going out of your way trying to help me. Unfortunately that didn't work. I downloaded the driver and when it checked for compatibility it said it couldn't find hardware on my computer that is compatible. I think this computer is just too old. It's ok though. I've opted to use my better computer to continue the fun. Thank you again for your help.